# Set all string properties of a class to empty in batch

Tags: c#, properties

The C# class have 20 properties in string. After some code execution, some of the properties are assgined value. Now I need a `Clear()` method to set all of them into `string.Empty`. I can write 20 lines of code, just assgin `string.Empty` to them one by one. But that will be a lot of lines in the class file.

Is there any good way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: 20 lines isn't that much and it is the fastest, otherwise do you really want to go down the `reflection` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a laugh ;)

```
string1 = string2 = string3 = string4 = string5 = string6 = string7 = string8 = string9 = string10 = string11 = string12 = string13 = string14 = string15 = string16 = string17 = string18 = string19 = string20 = string.Empty;
```